# Rails c sql command is rollingback instead of updating

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. so I tried to run rails c of this:

   ```
   Borrower.update(1, :raised=> 0)
   ```

   and this:

   ```
   Borrower.update(1, raised: 0)
   ```
2. and I get a roll back with this:

   ```
   Borrower Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "borrowers".* FROM "borrowers" WHERE "borrowers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   Borrower Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "borrowers" WHERE (LOWER("borrowers"."email") = LOWER('j@kay.com') AND "borrowers"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1

   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

   "table with raised = 0"
   1 row in set
   ```
3. This is my model for "Borrower":

   ```
   class Borrower < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :lenders
   has_many :histories, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :borrowed_from, through: :histories, source: :lender
   EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]+)\z/i
   validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :purpose, :description, :money, presence: true
   validates :email, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}, format: {with: EMAIL_REGEX}

   has_secure_password
   end
   ```
4. and my Schema:

   ```
   create_table "borrowers", force: :cascade do |t|

   t.string   "first_name"
   t.string   "last_name"
   t.string   "email"
   t.string   "password_digest"
   t.integer  "money"
   t.string   "purpose"
   t.text     "description"
   t.integer  "raised"
   t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
   end
   ```
5. How do I permanently update the "raised"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely the validation fails, try to print the validation errors on your console:

```
borrower = Borrower.update(1, raised: 0)
puts borrower.errors
```

Another solution if you want to explicitly skip the validation might be [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute):

```
Borrower.find(1).update_attribute(:raised, 0)
```

If you additionally want to skip the callbacks and avoid touching `updated_at` there's also [`update_column`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column):

```
Borrower.find(1).update_column(:raised, 0)
```

If `raised` is sort of a boolean attribute you could also go for [`toggle!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/toggle!):

```
Borrower.find(1).toggle!(:raised)
```

Comment: Thanks! the "Borrower.find(1).update_attribute(:raised, 0)" worked!